# How can I get from Ventimiglia to Antibes at night?

Tags: public-transport, europe, milan

I'm flying into Milan, getting in in the afternoon, and need to get to Antibes. I bought tickets on a 5pm train that gets into Ventimiglia at 9:15pm. Trouble is, their last train to Antibes leaves at 8:45pm.

I have 5 people. How can I get us to Antibes that night? Can I salvage this situation somehow?

Comment: Are you open to any options, for example, hitchhiking?

Comment: @MarkMayo Not open to hitchhiking, no.

Comment: A taxi will certainly take you, but for a price... Any cost constraints to consider?

Comment: @Gagravarr Do you know how much the taxi would be? Can we count on there being taxis at the Ventimiglia train station, or should we book in advance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see five ways to salvage the situation.

1. Spend the night in Milan and leave early on the following day. You will then be in Antibes around noon.
2. Take the train to Ventimiglia and spend the night there. On the following day, continue to Antibes. You will then be able to arrive in Antibes in the early morning
3. Rent a car in Milan, drive to Antibes and drop it there. It's a 4-5 hours drive. You will then arrive on Antibes in the late evening.
4. Take the evening train to Ventimiglia and continue to Antibes by taxi. You can expect this to cost around 200 EUR.
5. Take the evening train to Ventimiglia and then a train to Nice. The last trains leave at 21h49 and 22h40 from Ventimiglia. Nice you can take a taxi. Cost ~ 70 EUR

Comment: Also, fly to Nice, drive a taxi from your home, hire an helicopter, etc. but I take that the question implies that tickets have already been booked and changing the whole itinerary is too expensive. I don't think this answer properly addresses that.

Comment: Why not take the train to Nice (depart 21:49 - arrive 22:39) and then take the taxi? Would be cheaper this way.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea

Comment: @nicholaschris That's an excellent idea. It didn't occur to me that there would be more trains to Nice. Do you know if I should book a taxi in advance or can I expect to find some at the Nice station?

Comment: You are six persons arriving late in the evening. I would definitely book a van in advance. If you simply show up and hail a taxi at the station, chances are high that you won't find a van and that you will need to hail taxis ( = double the price).

Comment: There is a word missing in the last sentence: you will need to hail TWO taxis.